# Event Listener Scroll or Click

Tags: javascript, html, eventhandler

I have a web page with several sections.

To switch from one section to another I don't use scroll but everything is done by clicking (menu, pagination, arrows, etc...)

As soon as the user goes on a section, the background changes color, each section to its color.

I have no problem creating this kind of function but I have a performance question.

Or perhaps it's a question of logic I dunno

It would be better if I bind my event on the scroll and ask for the color change as soon as the section is in the right position

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', requestAnimationFrame(function(){

    if ( sectionPosition === 0 ){


        // Do something...
    }
}))
```

or it would be better if I bind my events on the different clickable elements with event delegation

```
     window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    let selector = event.target.getAttribute("href");


    if( selector === "#section-one"){

        //....
    }

    if(selector === "#section-two"){

        //....
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the second option is fine, adding listener on scroll will cause calling the callback with each px you scroll so make the action explicit is better than implicit with many unneeded calls

For the best you need to add click event listener on each element not on the whole window to avoid firing the click callback with any click.

To add click event on targeted item

```
const sectionOneEl = document.querySelector('#section-one');

sectionOneEl.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  // section one click handler
});
```

Comment: I'm ok with that but when I click on a clikable element the scroll event fire only once isn't it ?
User can't scroll directly in my configuration

Comment: Correct but still the scroll callbacks will be fired when any scroll happened into this page

Comment: Can you explain me that ?

Comment: When you `addEventListener` on scroll and anyone scroll, the scroll callback will be fired

try:

`window.addEventListener('scroll', e => console.log('scroll ev', e))`
The callback of it will be fired when you scroll

Comment: Is it not he same on a click event ?

Comment: You need to add click event on menu item you need not on whole window,
Click event will be fired only when you click on targeted element (menu item)

Comment: If I understand correctly, my console should show me several events when I click to go to a section? thank you for taking the time to explain to me

Comment: Scrol vent take 1ms more than the click event.it makes sense that I have to use the click event knowing that I will click forcibly before scroll